# How to parse uitextfield for send soap call?

Tags: ios, xcode, soap, uitextfield

I have 1 textfield and an static array. I have items in array like; 12345-NAME OF BRANCH. But I want send only 12345 from textfield to soap call. How can I do?

.h

```
 -(IBAction)Send:(UIButton *)sender;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *branches;
 @property (unsafe_unretained,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *BranchextField;
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)Send:(UIButton *)sender{

NSString *mensagemSOAP= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<UrunToplamiGetir xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"

                         "<BranchCode>%@</BranchCode>\n"
                         "</UrunToplamiGetir>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"_BranchextField.text];
          }
```

My arras is here

```
- (NSArray *)allbranches
{
    if(!self.branches){
        NSArray *branchNames = [self allCountries];
        NSMutableArray *mutablebranch = [NSMutableArray new];
        for(NSString *branchName in branchNames){
            DEMOCustomAutoCompleteObject *branch = [[DEMOCustomAutoCompleteObject alloc]
                                                    initWithBranch:branchName];
            [mutableBranches addObject:branch];
        }

        [self setBranchObjects:[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableBranch]];
    }

    return self.branches;
}

- (NSArray *)allBranches
{
    NSArray *branches =
    @[
      @"12345-NAME OF BRANCH",
      @"67853-BRANCH 2",
      @"43223-BRANHC 3",
      @"66532-BRANCH 4",
      @"76733-BRANCH 99",

      ];

    return countries;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this one

```
-(IBAction)Send:(UIButton *)sender
{
        NSString *numberString;

        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:_BranchextField.text];
        NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

        [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:NULL];

        // Collect numbers.
        [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString];

        NSLog(@"Number String %@",numberString);



              NSString *mensagemSOAP= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<UrunToplamiGetir xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"

                         "<BranchCode>%@</BranchCode>\n"
                         "</UrunToplamiGetir>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n",numberString];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

if `branches` have the same format like "number"-"name".

You can use `componentSeparatedByString:`  method of `NSString`

something like this:

```
NSArray *token = [textfield.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

if([token count]>0)
NSString *code = (NSString *)[token objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Can explain to me where I use this ?

Comment: -(IBAction)Send: put it before you compose the msgSoap.

Instead of passing BranchextField.text just pass code